# How do I get space before title?

Tags: poetry

I attempt to get larger space between the poem number and the title of the poem, but do not succeed. What should I do?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks, colorlinks=false, hidelinks}{hyperref}
\usepackage[numberpoems, clearpageafterpoem, useincipits]{poetrytex}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\setlength{\beforepoemtitleskip}{3.0in}

\begin{document}

\begin{poem}{Break, break, break}{Tennyson}

\begin{altverse}
% Incipits are used in the ToP if no title is given.
\incipit{Break, break, break},\\*
On thy cold gray stones, O Sea!\\*
And I would that my tongue could utter\\*
The thoughts that arise in me.
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
O, well for the fisherman's boy,\\*
That he shouts with his sister at play!\\*
O, well for the sailor lad,\\*
That he sings in his boat on the bay!
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
And the stately ships go on\\*
To their haven under the hill;\\*
But O for the touch of a vanish'd hand,\\*
And the sound of a voice that is still!
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
Break, break, break\\*
At the foot of thy crags, O Sea!\\*
But the tender grace of a day that is dead\\*
Will never come back to me.
\end{altverse}

\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interestingly, I can't find the definition of poem in either book or verse, only in memoir.

Comment: It is defined in poetrytex, and has nothing to do with verse, so \beforepoemtitleskip has no effect.

Comment: @JohnKormylo So what may I do?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Verse has \beforepoemtitleskip and poem.

Comment: Read the poetrytex manual.  There are several \vspace lengths defined, but I don't know what any of them do.  Or use \poemtitle from the verse package.

Comment: @JohnKormylo OK I hope someone can present an answer which works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution patching the `\titlepoemnum` command with the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{verse}
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks, colorlinks=false, hidelinks}{hyperref}
\usepackage[numberpoems, clearpageafterpoem, useincipits]{poetrytex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\titlepoemnum}{\vskip 4ex}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{poem}{Break, break, break}{\rule{0pt}{4ex}\itshape Alfred, Lord Tennyson}

\setlength{\leftskip}{8pc}
\begin{altverse}
% Incipits are used in the ToP if no title is given.
\incipit{Break, break, break},\\*
On thy cold gray stones, O Sea!\\*
And I would that my tongue could utter\\*
The thoughts that arise in me.
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
O, well for the fisherman's boy,\\*
That he shouts with his sister at play!\\*
O, well for the sailor lad,\\*
That he sings in his boat on the bay!
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
And the stately ships go on\\*
To their haven under the hill;\\*
But O for the touch of a vanish'd hand,\\*
And the sound of a voice that is still!
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
Break, break, break\\*
At the foot of thy crags, O Sea!\\*
But the tender grace of a day that is dead\\*
Will never come back to me.
\end{altverse}

\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That shifts she whole poem down. I want the extra space to be between I and the first occurrence of  Break, break, break.

Comment: Sorry, that was not clear to me. I'll see if I can adjust my answer.

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: I have posted another solution which  hopefully  does what you want.

Comment: Many thanks, and also for the \setlength{\leftskip}{8pc}! :)